# Merge Ranges with some Columns of same data

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016, vba

I have been trying to shape the piece of data as shown in the image below. The input are the three ranges `Range("B5:E11")`, `Range("G5:J11")` and `Range("L5:O11")` and the desired output `Range("B16:I26")`.

I basically opted to do that using VBA and the `.find` method inside three `for` loops, each for running through `B, G, L` columns each time. It got somewhat complicated, because, let's say you are in B column, once you search to find the same `name` in the others, `G, L`, then you also have to search for the `fruit`, so on. So, I got errors which made me stuck.

I would really appreciate if someone could share a way to handle this. 
I also know that Power Query is adequate for this kind of jobs, but neither looking there I could work this out.

[Merge Ranges with some Columns of same data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFZZw.png)

I paste the file here, in case someone is interested in having a look at it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6otpg1h74jewwe/Book1.xlsx?dl=0

Thank you all.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried in the original post.

Comment: The result isn't exactly what could be called fine coding.

Answer (score 0):

Using Power Query, I would start with a Query for each Month table, adding a columns for the month to each Query, e.g. Month = "April", Month Number = 4.

Then I would create an "Output" query which would use a series of Append steps to add the data from each Month Query.

This would deliver a "tidy data" table with a column for the month, which I would send to the Excel Data Model (Power Pivot). In Power Pivot I would set the Sort By Column for Month to the Month Number.

Finally I would then create a Pivot Table on the Data Model to achieve the required output, putting the Month field in the Columns well (to generate a column per month).